# JPA Entitties, how to join tables

Tags: java, jpa, hsqldb

I have three tables

```
CREATE TABLE "ingredient" (
  "id" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  "ingredient" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE "pizza" (
  "id" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  "pizza" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE "pizza_structure" (
  "pizza_id" INT NOT NULL,
  "ingredient_id" INT NOT NULL,
  "amount" INT NOT NULL
);
```

how to join them, to get Pizzas structure as a Map

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredient")
public class Ingredient{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Ingredient() {
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "pizza")
public class Pizza {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany ????
    private Map<Ingredient, Integer> pizzaStructure;

    public Pizza() {
    }

    public Pizza(String name, Map<Long, Integer> pizzaStructure) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pizzaStructure = pizzaStructure;
    }
}
```

do I need to create @Embeddable class PizzaStructure, if yes when how to use it?

now I'm getting an error
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to join them, to get Pizzas structure as a Map

It seems to look like this:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "pizza_structure", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pizza_id")})
@Column(name = "amount")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id")
private Map<Ingredient, Integer> pizzaStructure;
```

> do I need to create @Embeddable class PizzaStructure

No.

More info is here: [Hibernate User Guide - Maps](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-map).

Note that table `pizza_structure` should have foreign keys to `pizza` and `ingredient` tables and also unique constrain of `pizza_id` and `ingredient_id`, like this (it's postgresql dialect):

```sql
create table pizza_structure
(
  pizza_id ... constraint fk_structure_pizza references pizza,
  ingredient_id ... constraint fk_structure_ingredient references ingredient,
  amount ...,
  constraint pizza_structure_pkey primary key (pizza_id, ingredient_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a manyToMany relationship between pizza and ingredient and an additional column in your relationship.
I found a similar question here: [JPA 2.0 many-to-many with extra column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837561/jpa-2-0-many-to-many-with-extra-column)
(I would comment, but i do not have enough reputation.)