# JPA many-to-many with extra columns using @IdClass fails in springTestContextPreparation Hibernate AnnotationException "has no persistent id property"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to represent a bidirectional relationship with some entities using the `@IdClass` annotation as is shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32920550/8977519

I have a solution setup that follows the linked answer exactly and the application runs fine. I am able to use all of my CRUD end points and the changes are reflected in the DB. However, when I try to execute my tests the `springTestContextPrepareTestInstance` step fails.

***Composite Id Class***

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CompositeId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;

    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID entity1;
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID entity2;
}
```

***Bidirectional Entity Class***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bidirectional_entity")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass(CompositeId.class)
public class BidirectionalEntity {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Entity1 entity1;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity2_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Entity2 entity2;
    ...
}
```

***Entity Classes***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Entity1 {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity1",  orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private List<BidirectionalEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Entity2 {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity2",  orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private List<BidirectionalEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

The error given is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: {CompositeId Class} has no persistent id property
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: {CompositeId Class} has no persistent id property
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:2858)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.mapAsIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:1053)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:781)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
... 45 more
```

**Update**

After doing some novice debugging, in the Hibernate Core (5.3.9) `AnnotationBinder` class -> `bindIdClass` method the `componentId` object `properties` list is empty when performing setup for test(obviously, it's what is checked to throw the error). However, when running the program normally, there are two properties of `value` `org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue([org.hibernate.mapping.Column(entity*_id)])` with `name` entity*. Matching up with the `BidirectionalEntity` class as it should be.

Comment: Can you post the code for your @Entity and @Test?

Comment: @GabrielPimenta I added some code snippets. The tests aren't really anything special, they use `@SpringBootTest`, `@AutoconfigureMockMvc` and extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`. It doesn't seem like the actual test case code would be relevant as the setup fails before it attempts to execute any of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. Along with my service tests I was also writing tests to verify constraint validation annotations on POJOs. I forgot to add 'Test' to the end of the `CompositeId` test class name (`CompositeIdTest`). It seems that in the spring test context checking the test class was getting pulled in and checked for ID properties by Hibernate. Once I changed the test class name, tests starting running fine.