# How to create a JPA many to many mapping with custom lookup table?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

- Table1 (PK - x)
- Table2 (PK - y)

**Lookup Table (PK - [x, y]), z(additional attribute)**

I want to create Entity classes for Table1 and Table2 using JPA. Also, I want my Lookup Table to have some additional attributes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As you have additional attributes, you will need to map a classe for the relationship. Your many to many relationship thus becomes two many to one.

Comment: Probably you are trying to achieve something [like this](https://medium.com/@bhagyajayashani/composite-key-handling-using-embeddedid-annotation-in-spring-boot-java-67c29da9d119)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA 2.0 many-to-many with extra column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837561/jpa-2-0-many-to-many-with-extra-column)